# No autocomplete for PyQt4 in PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt4, pycharm

On my office PC I'm using

- Python 3.4
- PyQt4 Version 4.11.1
- PyCharm Community Eddition 3.4.1

I installed everything in the order as stated above.

However, code completion does not work. It works for imports, but not for classes and methods.

I made a small sample program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.setWindowTitle("Test")
window.resize(300, 200)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the code above none of the classes or methods were suggested by PyCharm.

If I type `window.setW` I would expect it to suggest `setWindowTitle()` but it doesn't.

Strange thing is, that I'm using the same setup on my computer at home and there it works like a (Py)charm... Autocompletion, auto imports, etc. As far as I remember I installed it the same way as I did on my office PC.

I already looked at some similiar questions but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159531/pycharm-autocomplete-does-not-work-for-pyqt-inherited-methods-mac) has no answers and others don't contain relevant information that helped me so far.

---

Don't know if it is relevant but at this line

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

PyCharm tells me

> Unresolved reference 'QtGui'

Maybe the reason for this is the same.

Comment: With same setup for my flask project I receive better code completion in professional edition. To be specific I have code completion for flask extensions while in community edition I have not. Trying with professional edition might help to figure out the problem. Moreover do you setup pycharm to use correct interpreter for your project? And do you use virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've set up the correct interpreter (I only got one installed) in project settings and build configurations. I'm not using virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing PyCharm first and then Python and PyQt.

Afterwards I had to configure the interpreter in PyCharm and it worked.

When I posted the question I installed Python, then PyQt and then PyCharm.

Oddly enough, it worked in this order on another PC.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem on Linux, pyqt5 and pycharm CE.
The solution was to rebuild the skeletons with:
    **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart.**

Comment: This seemed to work, but each time I fire up PyCharm the same thing happens. Is there a way to make this work permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue recently.  Unfortunately, the install order didn't solve it for me.

There is a bug report [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5131).  Downloading the Early Access Program release worked and can be found [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview+(EAP))