# Pycharm 3.4.1 on Windows 7 cannot generate skeletons for PyQt v4.11.2

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4, generator, pycharm

**ISSUE**
In PyCharm 3.4.1 on Windows 7 64bits, the skeleton generation for the PyQt library (v4.11.2, installed with the binary "PyQt4-4.11.2-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x64.exe") fails, which throws unresolved references when importing classes from the library, disabling any code completion feature. I had the project setup on a computer running Ubuntu with the exact same version, and everything was working fine.

**INSTALLATION INFORMATION**
The version of Python installed is 3.4.0 (and was tried with 3.4.1 as well, as I thought it might be that the PyQt library was working specifically with 3.4.0, not 3.4.1, but the issue it the same.) PyCharm was installed prior to Python, even though I doubt it makes any difference. Of course the PyQt library was installed after Python, and it is located in the site-packages of the Lib folder in my python34 folder, which is at the root of my C drive. If that's of any help, I have one other partition (D drive).

**RELATED INFORMATION**
After some research, I found that there were quite a bit of problems with skeleton generation with different libraries in PyCharm, many rather old (~2011) and which have been "fixed" since. No answer came up that worked in my case, including invalidate cache/restart PyCharm, reloading list of paths in the PyCharm interpreter, creating a VirtualEnv interpreter, running the generator3.py script in console.
Concerning that generator3.py script, it is the one responsible for creating the skeletons, and the odd thing is that when I run it in from console, python.exe crashes, which IMO is probably the root of the problem. I have not investigated the code contained in that file, but anyways I think that Python shouldn't crash, but report an error of some kind if there were a problem with it.

**Related issues**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782513/no-autocomplete-for-pyqt4-in-pycharm?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782513/no-autocomplete-for-pyqt4-in-pycharm?rq=1')

(Resolved by installing PyCharm first, which is already my case)

**Workaround**
Since I had the skeletons for the exact same version of Qt on my Ubuntu machine, I just copied the files to the folder holding the skeletons, a folder with a potentially random number located in ~.PyCharm30\system\python_stubs (I think there is one for each interpreter). The problem though is that PyCharm will try to generate it upon each startup, and override the file we manually copy, so to prevent it from doing so (since we can't disable automatic generation, annoying...) I made a backup of the generator3.py file and replaced it with a version with all the methods emptied and replaced with either pass or return True, such that PyCharm will think it has succeeded in generating the files, but it just takes the one we've copied.

Of course, this is pretty dirty and requires you to have the files already. I'll be kind and if that issue is after all a bug, you can use the skeleton files I used and the modified generator python file to make it work at least meanwhile they work on a fix.

Download the workaround: https://app.box.com/s/uulw818dfkzjdpyyty2y

Comment: This is great and everything, but stackoverflow is for questions and answers. You should probably post this at the [pycharm bugtracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard/PY); it is not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: I have a question (refer to the issue part), I'd like an answer. I give information to help find the answer (which might indeed result in being a bug, but I don't know that just yet). If someone answers saying it's a bug in PyCharm or python itself, it will result in the question being answered and I'll fill-in a bug. Plus other related question exist, which just happens that their answer doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You are basically filing a bug report; this is not what stackoverflow is for. Post it directly at the bug tracker for pycharm. Especially as you have already solved the problem.

Comment: I see your point, I suggested a workaround for people looking for a solution on short-term. But I'd really want to know if it's just me, especially since it works on another platform. Thanks for the link though, I've found a ticket similar to my issue which I haven't found before.

Comment: My point is that _**stackoverflow is not the platform for such discussions**_ Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but might be useful to others: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14235, for details on getting a working set of skeletons for other versions of PyQt.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's steps toward applying my workaround (which are already described in the readme).

Comment: I'm aware of that: but given that your post is not a question I felt it appropriate to post an answer that is not an answer :) It may help others, as your post helped me (I have plussed it). I am not expecting an Accept or even any votes.

Comment: The question wad if it was an issue with PyCharm. The answer is that it is as far as I'm concerned. I just feel an answer shouls be posted when the issue will be resolved, even though StackOverflow is not a ticket service, its rank on Google makes it the quickest source to find information on the very issue. Didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: No problem, I understand why you used SO and I'm glad you did. Perhaps however you could move the "answer" portion of your post to an answer then accept it, I would certainly upvote it.

Comment: That sounds good, I guess I just thought of the whole topic as not SO-friendly and basically discarded it, but it seems it's useful so that's what I'll do.