# Can't access PyQt functions in PyCharm

Tags: pyqt, pycharm

I've recently installed Pycharm and PyQt to start application development, but I can't seem to access the PyQt functions in my projects. The same code works if I open an example of PyQt, but if I paste it in my project, I get these squiggly underlines and an error upon compile.

Comment: Can you be more specific: what makes you say it doesn't work, did you type something, what are the symptoms of the problem.

Comment: Hi Schollii, If I import something from the QT library (like QApplication) I get these squiggly lines at the bottom and it fails to recognize the functions in the code below.If I run an example of QT in the site-packages It runs fine, but if I copy paste the same code in my project it fails to recognize those functions. Plus I also get this warning that pycharm failed to load 17 skeletons.

Comment: Please can you extend your post with this info instead of answering in a comment? It is not just a detail, it is the essence of the question. On SO try to make your question as self contained as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the pycharm skeleton file generator, encounters issues with some pyqt files, there is no pattern as to why this happens. I have had similar issue with pyqt 5.3 and the pycharm 3.4.1. I and several others spent hours on the issue, browsing the web for clues and trying everything suggested to no avail.

We eventually found a [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447557/pycharm-3-4-1-on-windows-7-cannot-generate-skeletons-for-pyqt-v4-11-2) that indicated a solution. In our case applying it was quite simple: we did not observe this problem with pyqt 5.2 therefore we copied the skeleton files from that version into the 5.3 skeletons folder. The details of how to do this are available in a comment that I posted on the pycharm bug tracking site: [PyCharm auto completion doesn't work for PyQt 5.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14235). The issue is discussed in other ticket I just found, which might provide an actual fix instead of just a temporary patch: [Unresolved reference in PyQt for QtGui module](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5131).

Comment: Do you still have those skeleton files? Can you upload them somewhere? I'm having exactly the same problem, except I can't find *any* combinations of Python and Qt that work correctly.

Comment: @matt The problem is gone in pycharm 4.0.4

Comment: I wish that were the case. I upgraded to 4.04 because others reported that the problem evaporated, but it's still very much a problem for me. http://imgur.com/EEat8Et

Comment: The actual code runs fine, though; I've just got to slog through the documentation every time I want to call a method and can't remember the exact text of the method name -- like programmers used to do in the "bad old days"

Comment: @matt Have you tried both pyqt 5.2 and 5.3 with 4.0.4?

Comment: I've tried two combinations (Python2.7/PyQt5.3.1 -- via https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5) and (Python3.4/PyQt5.4 via http://www.riverbankcomputing.com). Where can I get sources/binaries for older versions? Riverbank doesn't link an archive on its downloads page.

Comment: @matt I would only download one of the Stock installers from the pyqt website and use the corresponding Python version. So you should be able to try three versions of pyqt and I can't remember which versions of python you will need; one of those should work properly in pycharm 4..

Comment: \@schollii, it still won't work with the stock installers off Riverbank, Python 3.4, and Pycharm 4.04, even on a fresh installation of windows. I'm out of ideas. So is the rest of the internet. Can you upload the skeletons that your system generated? PyQt5.2 and 5.3 are no longer available; only 5.4, which doesn't generate skeletons.

Answer (score 0):

Late , but after none of above methods not work I closed `pycharm` and restarted pyCharm by `restarter.exe` in this path:`C:\Users\<user-name>\.PyCharm2016.2\system\restart` , then reopened pycharm. In my case it just worked :)